# Animation Nodes: How to hiccup letters individually?

Tags: animation-nodes

I have three examples that I wish to mimic with Animation Nodes. Any assistance is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

The first example below shows letters hopping straight up and down. 
The second hops up with rotation and down. 
The last hops up while spreading outwards and down. 
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you give your reasons for choosing AN here, as opposed to conventional keyframing?

Comment: One, I really want to learn Animation Nodes for future projects with motion graphics. I'm very keen on learning the uses of Animation Nodes. Two, I have long sentences & paragraphs and that would be laborious. I reckon Animation Nodes would speed up the labour. Three, I am relearning maths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first effect can be achieved very similarly to my answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/122656/animation-nodes-how-do-i-make-text-hiccup). The inverse of a delay falloff is used to offset the matrices of each of the characters by scaling them to zero and moving them in the negative y direction:

[image: First Effect]

The second effect can be achieved by introducing a rotation to each character. The rotation of each character will linearly depend on its index, where the rotation of the first character is some negative scalar and the rotation of the last character is some positive scalar:

[image: Second Effect]

The third effect can be achieved by introducing a linear offset along the x axis based on the index of the characters, this is done similar to the second effect as follows:

[image: Third Effect]

Comment: This is very helpful. Many thanks. I am learning new nodes everyday, thanks to your contribution.